# RadioButton 'android:button' does nothing

Tags: android, radio-button, android-drawable

I've tried to change the drawable of the checked button on a RadioButton but nothing is showing; setting the drawable just removes the default one that is already there.

I used stack overflow to try find a solution but when I try to implement it, there is not drawable showing up. My selector appears to be fine because when I set the `background` of the radio button that displays my circles.

I'm sure it's a very obvious problem which I'll slap myself for not seeing; can anyone figure out what is wrong?

My Radio Buttons

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left"
            android:checked="false"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button" />
        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/radio_button"
            android:text="Right"
            android:checked="true" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

With my selector

[image: with selector]

Without my selector

[image: without selector]

My Selector XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_checked"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/radio_button_unchecked" />
</selector>
```

radio_button_checked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/primary_button_color"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="2px"
        android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

radio_button_unchecked.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <stroke
        android:width="2px"
        android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't see anything because your drawable don't have any size.

Try to define `<size android:width="60dp" android:height="60dp"/>` under the shape of your xml.

Answer (score 1):

## Your Problem

As you see, `RadioButton` extends `CompoundButton`. When you do not use your selector, there is a default drawable.Let's see its constructor.

```
   public CompoundButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.CompoundButton, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

    final Drawable d = a.getDrawable(com.android.internal.R.styleable.CompoundButton_button);
    if (d != null) {
        setButtonDrawable(d);
    }
```

The default drawable is `R.styleable.CompoundButton_button` whose `intrinsicWidth = 96px` and `intrinsicHeight = 96px` on my device.

When you use your selector, the `drawable`'s `intrinsicWidth = -1px` and `intrinsicHeight = -1px` so you can not see it.

## Solution

You should define your drawable's size.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="oval">
<size android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp"/>
<stroke
    android:width="2px"
    android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```